# Powershell Adding multiple arrays of different columns to a main array

Tags: arrays, powershell, multidimensional-array

Code:

```
$arr1 = "" | select blabla,blabla2
$arr2 = "" | select blabla3,blabla4

$arrtotal = @()
$arrtotal += $arr1
$arrtotal += $arr2

$arrtotal
```

Printout:

> blabla blabla2
>
> ---

However, when attempting to print both cells individually (not one after the other but simply selecting in PS ISE and hitting F8):

```
$arrtotal[0]
```

> blabla blabla2
>
> ---

```
$arrtotal[1]
```

> blabl3 blabla4
>
> ---

EDITED:
I would have expected both array columns to be printed when printing $arrtotal. Not just one of them. Further more it's unclear to me why printing them individually works but one after the other i.e "$arrtotal[0];$arrtotal[1]" does not.

EDIT2:

This is my original code.
All it does is query Sparkpost's API in order to build a custom HTML report.

```
$test = (Invoke-WebRequest "https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/metrics/deliverability?metrics=count_injected,count_sent,count_bounce,count_accepted&from=2016-01-01T08:00&to=2016-04-25T08:00" -Headers @{"Authorization"="xxxxxxxxxxxxx";"Content-Type"= "application/json"}).content | ConvertFrom-Json

$fill1 = "" | select EmailsReceived,EmailsSent,EmailsBounced

$fill1.EmailsReceived = $test.results.count_injected
$fill1.EmailsSent = $test.results.count_accepted
$fill1.EmailsBounced = $test.results.count_bounce

$fill2 = "" | select DeliveredPrecentage,BouncesPrecentage
$fill2.DeliveredPrecentage = [math]::round($test.results.count_accepted/$test.results.count_injected*100,2)
$fill2.BouncesPrecentage = [math]::round(($test.results.count_bounce)/$test.results.count_accepted*100,2)

$arr = @()

$arr += , $fill1
$arr += , $fill2
```

My problem is that I cant simply convert $arr into an HTML file like I've done numerous times before.

```
$arr
```

> EmailsReceived EmailsSent EmailsBounced
>
> ---
>
> ```
>        107        107            12
> ```

On the other hand

```
$arr | Format-List
```

> EmailsReceived : 107 EmailsSent     : 107 EmailsBounced  : 12
>
> DeliveredPrecentage : 100 BouncesPrecentage   : 11.21

I'd like to make an HTML out of everything so I can send it via email later. How can I pipe it all?

Comment: What is the question? What do you expect?

Comment: I'll edit my post.

Comment: Added the missing declaration $arrtotal = @()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `$arr1`and `$arr2`are two different `PSCustomObjects`. You can print the whole `array`in a list using the [Format-List](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113302) cmdlet:

```
$arrtotal | Format-List
```

*Output:*

```
blabla  : 
blabla2 : 

blabla  : 
blabla2 :
```

**Answer to your edit:**

This looks like a single record for me, try this:

```
$record = [PsCustomObject]@{
    EmailsReceived = $test.results.count_injected
    EmailsSent = $test.results.count_accepted
    EmailsBounced = $test.results.count_bounce
    DeliveredPrecentage = [math]::round($test.results.count_accepted/$test.results.count_injected*100,2)
    BouncesPrecentage = [math]::round(($test.results.count_bounce)/$test.results.count_accepted*100,2)
}

$record | convertto-html | out-file file.html
```

Note: I also changed the logic to create the object to a more well known approach using a `PsCustomObject` typecast on a *hashtable*.

Comment: If I wanted to do a $arrtotal | convertto-html | out-file file.html, how can I output all columns?

Comment: You do have two objects with each having two different columns. It depends what output you want. Also, maybe you can add an additional example with some data in it.

Comment: That's brilliant!
Question, when should I use a hashtable and when should I use an array? Also, I suppose I could use a hashtable of 2 arrays so that the columns would be in 2 lines.

Comment: you use a hashtable if you want to define something like object properties and you use an array whenever you want to store multiple items of something.